# How to force Panels to render a node field even when field is empty

Tags: 7, views, entities, panels

I have a field that I want to display via the [Views Hybrid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_hybrid) formatter in a panel pane as a node element. It renders just fine when there is at least one user-selected item in the field, but when there is none, it is treated as an empty field and so none of the view results show either. The whole thing is not displayed just because the field is empty.

How can I force panels to render a node element even when the field contains zero values?

Comment: Does https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields work in Panels?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried it and it doesn't seem to be saving its settings properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i wanted to render an empty field in a panel was because the views hybrid formatter shows a view when the field is empty.  Instead,  i ended up showing the view via a views pane and making that pane conditional on the value of the field being empty.